# Parsing Data in Silverlight

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-4.0

I have a design question about parsing data in Silverlight.  I need to allow my users to validate their csv data (they paste ten rows into a textblock), but I am not sure if I should attempt to do it on the client side where I don't have access to the textfileparser class or send the data to a webservice for validation.  If I send it to a webservice how do I ensure the data is secure?  Any help is appreciated.

Wade